# mysqldump error on simple python code

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql

I run the following simple python 2.7 code;

```
   dumpcmd = "mysqldump -u " + DB_USER + " -p" + DB_USER_PASSWORD + " " + db + " > " + TODAYBACKUPPATH + "/" + db + ".sql"
   os.system(dumpcmd)
```

The error I got is as follows;

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SET OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1': You have an er
ror in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server v
ersion for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1' at line
 1 (1064)
```

The strange thing is that my python code does not contain anything like `SET OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1` as mentioned in the error. Can someone advise?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Can you please show where all those constants are defined?

Comment: @ javidcf: I am using MySQL 5.6.16

Comment: I got the python code here http://tecadmin.net/python-script-for-mysql-database-backup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to happen because you are using `mysqldump` 5.5 or prior with a MySQL 5.6 database. The `SET OPTION` syntax was removed (see discussion in [this bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66765)), causing this tool to stop working.

You will need to update your version of `mysqldump`. More info about it in [this other bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67507).

Comment: Thanks. But the strange thing is that in my python code, there is no code like `SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1`

Comment: @user3293156 Sorry, you are right, I misread the code. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might need a space between `-p` and `DB_USER_PASSWORD`.

```
dumpcmd = "mysqldump -u " + DB_USER + " -p " + DB_USER_PASSWORD + " " + db + " > " + TODAYBACKUPPATH + "/" + db + ".sql"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Perhaps try using `from subprocess import call
call(["mysqldump", "-u", DB_USER, "-p", DB_USER_PASSWORD, ...])` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer from javidcf, I found the answer to my question. The solution is to use a command-line mysqldump version that supports  MySQL 5.6.